# Como definir um breakpoint no gdb para todas funções de certo arquivo?

Tags: debug, gdb, breakpoints

É possivel definir um breakpoint para todas funções de um determinado arquivo no gdb? Uma aplicação, por exemplo, seria verificar se o programa passa por certo arquivo durante sua execução.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o `rbreak`, que define breakpoints de acordo com uma expressão regular. Para setar breakpoints em todas funções do arquivo `arquivo.c`, utilize o seguinte comando:

```
(gdb) rbreak arquivo.c:.
```

Mais informações, na [documentação](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Breaks.html).